# Delete an image using link/id from database

Tags: php, sql

I want to delete an image by an button called 'DELETE'.
My image is saved on the server, my image link is saved into a database table.

To delete now works great, but every user can delete every users images right now by typing in the picture id in the URL.

**uploads.php**

```
<div id="myuploads">
<?php
//Configuration
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'myimg';

$salt = "u6d5u6mj65dehjum568nuu65umk57endjzu766imm57e8u5u56";

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $hash = hash('sha224', $_SESSION['username']).$salt;
}

$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");

//Script
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $uid = $_SESSION['username'];
    $dir = $uid . "/";

    $alledateien = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM imglinks WHERE uid='$uid'");

    foreach ($alledateien as $datei)
    {

        echo "<div class='pictures'> \
              <img class='pbild' src='" . $dir . $datei["link"] . "'><br/> \ 
              <form action='functions/deleteimg.php'></div> \
              <input class='deleteimg' type='submit' name='deleteimg' value='DELETE'> \
              <input class='post' type='submit' value='PUBLISH'></form>";
    }
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
</div>
```

**deleteimg.php**

```
<?php
include '../config.php';

$uid = $_SESSION['username'];

$username = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT uid FROM imglinks WHERE uid='$uid'");

foreach($username AS $name) {

if(isset($_GET['deleteimg']) && $uid = $name['uid']){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM imglinks WHERE id='".$_GET['deleteimg']."' LIMIT 1";

    $filepath = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    foreach($filepath AS $value) {
        unlink($value['link']);
    }

    $uid = $_SESSION['username'];
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM imglinks WHERE id='".$_GET['deleteimg']."' AND uid='$uid'");
}}
```

The links given out coming out of the imglinks table of my database.

[DATABASE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAnua.png)

If you need more detail, feel free to ask.

Comment: You can have a form with hidden input and use the $uid as value, then delete the image by finding it using it's link in the database !

Comment: value='DELETE'  value should be the image_ID for easy reference to tht image

Comment: @Soheyl could you explain it a bit further?

Comment: can you send your database structure for your images pls ?

Comment: @Soheyl I have added it.

Comment: Update your question and add code of `deleteimg.php`... just want to know how you are deleting it right now?

Comment: @ d.coder I'm sorry, i still have not figured out how i can delete it the right way. I need to adress the delete button of each image right.

Comment: So images are saved like this ? root/$uid/imgname ?

Comment: @Soheyl Yep, hash(imgname).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I would suggest / do when deleting I would use an anchor tag instead of a button to delete then on the anchor tag I will have action and id as query string. then on the deleteimg.php page I will query the action and the ID if the action is delete then delete the selected id.

Then you code will look like this :

**uploads.php**

```
<div id="myuploads">
<?php
//Configuration
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'myimg';

$salt = "u6d5u6mj65dehjum568nuu65umk57endjzu766imm57e8u5u56";

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $hash = hash('sha224', $_SESSION['username']).$salt;
}

$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");

//Script
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $uid = $_SESSION['username'];
    $dir = $uid . "/";

    $alledateien = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM imglinks WHERE uid='$uid'");

    foreach ($alledateien as $datei)
    {

        echo "<div class='pictures'> \
              <img class='pbild' src='" . $dir . $datei["link"] . "'><br/> \ 
              <form action='functions/deleteimg.php'></div> \
              <a class='deleteimg' href='functions/deleteimg.php?action=delete&id='".$datei['id']."'>DELETE</a><br>
              <input class='post' type='submit' value='PUBLISH'></form>";
    }
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
</div>
```

Then **deleteimg.php**

```
<?php

    // Your connection here...

    // check if session is set here...



      $action = $_GET['action'];
      $img_id = intval($_GET['id']);


      if($action === "delete"){

      $sql = "DELETE FROM imglinks WHERE id='$img_id'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
//image delete... do something else

    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

      }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

This always works for me and always easy, hope you will find it useful.

**NB: Read about mysqli prepared statements, against sql injections.. You can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**

Comment: That's a nice way too, i will try it later :)

Comment: the right code would look like this: `<a class='deleteimg' href='functions/deleteimg.php?deleteimg=".$datei['id']."'>DELETE</a>`

Thanks, this is the solution i will use.

Comment: Then u will need to change this line `$img_id = intval($_GET['id']);`  as well.

Comment: Can you explain why?
My code works fine without this!

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Add a boolean field to your *imglinks* table named say 'show', and modify your query accordingly. In this case you'll be even able to 'undelete' accidentally deleted images.
2. If you're short on disk space then modify `<input class='deleteimg' type='submit' name='deleteimg' value='DELETE'>` to  `<input class='deleteimg' type='submit' name='deleteimg' value='".$image_to_delete."'>` so that you'll see this link in your postdata and will be able to process it

Comment: Hm if I'm right the $image_to_delete = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT imgname FROM imglinks WHERE uid='$uid'"); ?

Comment: if you don't assign unique names to images while uploading, then yes, but if you do, then  just a filename will serve

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your buttons like this:

```
foreach ($alledateien as $datei)
{

    echo "<div class='pictures'> \
          <img class='pbild' src='" . $dir . $datei["link"] . "'><br/> \ 
          </div><form action='functions/deleteimg.php'> \
          <input type='hidden' name='img_id' value='".$datei["id"]."'> \
          <input class='deleteimg' type='submit' name='deleteimg' value='DELETE'> \
          <input class='post' type='submit' name='publish' value='PUBLISH'></form>";
}
```

Then on `deleteimg.php`, get the image id and execute a delete query:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteimg']) && $_POST['deleteimg'] == 'DELETE'){
    $img_id = $_POST['img_id'];
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM imglinks WHERE id='$img_id'");
}
```

Comment: Ah that's a very simple & nice way to solve it, thanks!
is there in PHP the possibility to mask the value of an input? So the button is still called 'DELETE'?

Comment: Well, in that case we will have to change the way we are doing it right now. We need to keep this ID in hidden field.

Comment: But you already have two submit button and both will submit the form. So, on `deleteimg.php`, you need to check which button was clicked.

Comment: The two submit buttons in one form is just a little fault my side.
So, how i can set it to hidden?

Comment: Answer updated. BTW, you can use links (<a> tags) instead of hidden field and form like as explained by @Masivuye Cokile.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now every works great except one: The user should just can delete his own pictures. At the moment he only can delete his own database entrys `mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM imglinks WHERE id='".$_GET['deleteimg']."' AND uid='$uid'");` , but if he changes the value of 'deleteimg' he can delete images from the server of every user. I have tried it in my deleteimg.php, i've added it to my question, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not so complicated, just use like this :

*Root is your root directory !

```
$path = root/$uid/$imgname;

$query("DELETE FROM imagetable WHERE imgname = $imgname");
```

And to delete the image :

```
unlink($path);
```

And just use a form to submit imgname to your script !

*For more security, you can also add $uid to your query !

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: So I think I didn't understand your question :D what is it exactly ?

Comment: My path is saved in my database, so i want to set the button to the picture ID, so i can adress the button to the right picture. The SQL query for deleting and the unlink function are known in my head.

Comment: Okay so as I just explained in my comments, you can have a form with your imgname and uid in two hidden inputs and just get them as _POST to your delete script and delete the image ! You have uid and imgname, you don't need fancy job to do ! I am sorry but I didn't understand your problem in this case !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers, now i've completed it myself.

**deleteimg.php**

```
<?php
include '../config.php';

$uid = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_GET['deleteimg'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM imglinks WHERE id='".$_GET['deleteimg']."' LIMIT 1";
    $filepath = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $test = mysqli_fetch_array($filepath);

    if($test['uid'] == $uid){
        unlink($test['link']);
        mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM imglinks WHERE id='".$_GET['deleteimg']."' AND uid='$uid'");

        echo 'File successfully deleted.';
        header ("Refresh: 2; ../index.php");

    } else {
        echo 'You do not have the permission to delete this file.';
        header ("Refresh: 2; ../index.php");
    }


}
```